# Plotting route between 2 points in android

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to draw path from one location to other location. How to plot the path between the two locations. I have coordinates(latitude,longitude) for both locations. How can i achieve this functionality? I am working on android sdk 2.2 . I don't want to use kml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr="+ latitude + "," + Longitude+ "&daddr="+latitudeDb+","+longitudeDb+""));
 intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps","com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

You Can Use Following Intent and pass Your Source and destination latitude and longitude ,and 
Next Actvity shows Path Between your geo points.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will server your need (from google) - http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/

Comment: can you please give a more specific example ?